# unrecognized selector sent to instance when trying to open new viewController

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've got 2 viewControllers:

1. DemoAppViewController
2. AboutViewController

I have an info button in DemoAppViewController which is supposed to open AboutViewController.

At the moment I'm getting a run time error and i can't seem to work out why..

Here's the code:

DemoAppViewController .h:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo;
```

DemoAppViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo {

    AboutViewController *controller = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];



    //setting style with modalTransition property

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;



    //show on screen

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

When i create the AboutViewController object with `initWithNibName` xCode adds the following code to AboutViewController.m:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization

    }

    return self;

}
```

I've left the above untouched.

Runtime error:

```
[DemoAppViewController showInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x688e450
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector for this method is `@selector(showInfo)`, not `@selector(showInfo:)`. If you assign it programmatically, just correct it. If you use IB - add `:(id) sender` parameter to the method.